# scipy returns nan for cauchy distribution

Tags: python, scipy

I am new to scipy and I met with a problem on moment values of cauchy distribution.

My code is pretty simple:

```
from scipy.stats import cauchy
print(cauchy.stats(moments='m'))
```

The command line returns *nan*. I followed tutorial on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.cauchy.html
and it also returns nan moment values. Is this a bug of scipy?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Explanation_of_undefined_moments